# Convert Date in Dart Unhandled Exception: FormatException: Invalid date format

Tags: dart

How can I convert **28 Jul 2017** to **2017-07-28** in dart. I have tried
**DateTime.parse** and **formatter** both are not working.

Comment: Just for clarification, the name of the months are always going to be in English?

Comment: Yes in three letter format

Comment: Ok, but why are `Jul` then the 6th month? :)

Comment: Edited the quest. You are July is 7th month. Thank you for the observation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using the `intl` package you can do something like this:

```dart
import 'package:intl/intl.dart';

void main() {
  DateFormat dateFormatInput = DateFormat('dd MMM yyyy');
  DateTime parsedDateTime = dateFormatInput.parse('28 Jul 2017');
  print(parsedDateTime); // 2017-07-28 00:00:00.000

  DateFormat dateFormatOutput = DateFormat('yyyy-MM-dd');
  String formattedDateTime = dateFormatOutput.format(parsedDateTime);
  print(formattedDateTime); // 2017-07-28
}
```

Comment: Fantastic this is working perfectly. That's what I wanted thank you.